# Как добавить в AWX docker callback плагин

Tags: ansible

Установлен AWX docker отсюда - https://github.com/ansible/awx Пытаюсь добавить callback плагин для конкретного проекта как написано  здесь - https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/administration/tipsandtricks.html#using-callback-plugins-with-tower Не работает. Добавляю в Template - EXTRA VARIABLES строки

```
---
bin_ansible_callbacks: true
callback_plugins: /callback_plugins
stdout_callback: selective
```

Не работает.

Добавляю в SETTINGS->JOBS->ANSIBLE CALLBACK PLUGINS директорию `/var/lib/awx/projects/test/callback_plugins/`- тоже не работает.

Подскажите, плиз, как правильно сделать, чтобы подхватился другой (кастомный) плагин.

Answer (score 0):

В файле нсатройки явно укажите что вам нужно:

*/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg*

```
...
callback_plugins = ~/.ansible/plugins/callback:/usr/share/ansible/plugins/callback
callback_whitelist = timer,mail
...
```

Ansible ищет файл конфигурации от локального до глобального, если был найдет локальный файл, используется он.
Попробуйте без AWX запустить ваши плейбуки для отладки.

**Ссылки**

- https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/intro_configuration.html#callback-plugins

Comment: Да, все правильно. Но только для Ansible - для терминала, Visual Code, PyCharm и иже с ними. Все так и есть и все работает. Вопрос про AWX и Tower. Нужно разобраться именно с Tower. За ответ спасибо.